# How to filter a richfaces dataTable according to user role

Tags: java, security, richfaces, seam, filtering

I am working on a Seam project (Seam 2) with two types of user roles.  Normal users, and users with sensitive information privileges.  The latter have access to a set of database records marked "sensitive" that coexist with normal records, and are marked by a particular column value.

I have used #{s:hasRole('SENSITIVE')} to hide other portions of the UI as appropriate, but I would like to filter the actual richfaces dataTable in which the records are displayed, so that sensitive records do not appear for normal users.  Is there a way to do this at the presentation layer, or do I need to filter the rows on the server based on user role?

Comment: Did you try the filter related properties in DataTable. please [look at](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dataTable.jsf?tab=info&cid=147) the properties their.

Comment: I may have misread these, but I thought they were aimed at adding filter boxes to individual columns.  I will play with these properties for a bit and see what happens though.

Comment: Well, I guess I did misunderstand what I read.  If you want to post this as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it :)

Specifically, the filterExpression lets you put an arbitrary EL expression in there, and when I just put it on my first column, it prevents the entire row from appearing.

Comment: Good to hear you solved your problem, I put the statement as an answer now you can accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the filter related properties in DataTable. please look at the properties their:

http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dataTable.jsf?tab=info&cid=147